# c++ Hold instructions for a later time

Tags: c++, user-interface, methods, draw, instructions

I am trying to design a UIDraw method. I want to declare what UI elements to draw in the main Draw method But then Have a separate UIDraw Method later in the code. So I need a way to store instructions to execute in this new function. I hope it makes sense.
Something like this:

```
        Draw();
        DrawUI();
```

But say what UI to draw in the Draw() function.
Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions only. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out what you can ask on here.

Comment: _"Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?"_ Using  optional parameters for the specific UI elements maybe?

Comment: @NikitaDemodov The question is specific enough for me?

Comment: Make a std::vector of std::functions maybe, then later iterate over the vector and call all the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle this problem depending on what *exactly* you need. One approach popular in the OO world is the so called [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (similar approaches exist in other programming paradigms, they just have either different names or are considered so obvious they don't even get a specific name at all).

The basic idea is this: You want to execute some command, but the time you want to execute the command and the time you decide *what* command to execute are different. So the way to solve this problem is to simply create an object that contains the information you need to execute the command, pass that object to the place that decides when the execution should happen, and then that code can run the command as it pleases.

Here’s a mockup of what that might look like in C++ (note: didn't actually compile this code, might contain minor errors – just meant to convey the idea).

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

/// this is an abstract class that gives us an interface to use
class DrawCommand {
  public:
  virtual void Draw() = 0;
};

/// one kind of thing you might want to draw
class DrawTree : public DrawCommand {
  public:
  void Draw() override {
     // tree drawing code
  }
};

/// another kind of thing you might want to draw
class DrawCat : public DrawCommand {
  public:
  void Draw() override {
    // cat drawing code
  }
};

/// we can even come up with ways to combine these in interesting ways
class DrawABunchOfThings : public DrawCommand {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DrawCommand>> things;
  public:
  DrawABunchOfThings(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DrawCommand>> things)
    : things{std::move(things)}
  {}

  void Draw() override {
    for(auto &thing : things) {
      thing->Draw();
    }
  }
};

/// this is where we decide what we will draw
std::unique_ptr<DrawCommand> PrepareDraw() {
  if(someCondition) {
    // just a cat
    return std::make_unique<DrawCat>();
  } else if(someOtherCondition) {
    // just a tree
    return std::make_unique<DrawTree>();
  } else {
    // forest with a cat hidden inside
    return std::make_unique<DrawABunchOfThings>(
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DrawCommand>>{
        std::make_unique<DrawTree>(),
        std::make_unique<DrawTree>(),
        std::make_unique<DrawCat>()
        std::make_unique<DrawTree>(),
      }
    );
  }
}

/// this is where we will do the actual drawing
/// note that any arbitrary amount of code can go between
/// PrepareDraw and ExecuteDraw
void ExecuteDraw(DrawCommand &command) {
  // this can of course have a bunch of elaborate
  // code here as well -- also, DrawCommand::Draw might
  // take extra parameters here, like 2D or 3D transforms,
  // time since we last drew something, or whatever
  command.Draw();
}
```

---

Note that if you only need a single method on this thing C++ already has this in the form of `std::function`, so you could just say `using DrawCommand = std::function<void()>;` and be done with it, which would also immediately allow you to use it with lambdas:

```
int nTimes = 10;
DrawCommand drawNTimesCommand = [nTimes]() {
  for(int i = 0; i < nTimes; ++i) {
    // draw something
  }
};

// --- any code you like here ---

// actually execute the draw command
drawNTimesCommand();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new at c++ (used to unity) so this is all new to me. But this has taught me a lot! Thank you very much!!